# How do I override TreeNodeCollection.Add(TreeNode)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenodecollection

I have this:

```
public abstract class DRT_Tvw_Abstract : TreeView
{
    TableCountMetrics metrics;
    public TableCountMetrics Metrics { get => metrics; set => metrics = value; }

    public class TableCountMetrics
    {
        int schemaNameCount = 0;
        int tableNameCount = 0;

        public int SchemaNameCount { get => schemaNameCount; set => schemaNameCount = value; }
        public int TableNameCount { get => tableNameCount; set => tableNameCount = value; }
    }

    public DRT_Tvw_Abstract() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class DRT_Tvw_TableList_Unfiltered : DRT_Tvw_Abstract
{
    public DRT_Tvw_TableList_Unfiltered() : base()
    {
    }

    public void _CreateTreeView(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        tableListTreeViewNode = new {treeview node from my class that derives from TreeNode}

        Nodes.Add(tableListTreeViewNode);       
}
```

What I want to do is `override` the `Add` method so I can increment/decrement custom integer properties that are part of my `DRT_Tvw_Abstract` class at the same time I `Add` a `TreeNode`. I started by trying to derive from the `TreeNodeCollection` class, but that seems to be a dead-end because I can't figure out what a valid ctor is for the `TreeNodeCollection` class

`Nodes` (as in `Nodes.Add`) is a property. How do I derive from it so I can override the `Add` method? I started by creating an override for this poprperty, but I have no clue as to how you override a method (`Add`) from within property override code.

```
public new virtual TreeNodeCollection Nodes
{

    //override the Add method from within here somehow?

    get
    {
        return base.Nodes;
    }

    set
    {
    }
}
```

What is the syntax for overriding the TreeNodeCollection class Add(TreeNode) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Add` method belongs to [`TreeNodeCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class. If you like to have new `Add` methods with new signatures:

- Naturally you may think about deriving from `TreeNodeCollection` and defining new methods and derive from `TreeView` and replace its `TreeNodeCollection` with your new custom node collection. But don't try this solution. `TreeNodeCollection` doesn't have a public constructor. So I'd suggest creating [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).
- The other solution that you may think about it is deriving from `TreeView` and adding new `Add` methods to the derived `TreeView`.

**Example - Extension Methods**

Create a new code file and copy the following code and paste it in the code file:

```
namespace MyExtensions
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    public static class TreeNodeCollectionExtensions
    {
        //Just an example of a new signature, use the signature that you need instead:
        public static TreeNode Add(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, string text, int tag)
        {
            var node = nodes.Add(text);
            node.Tag = tag;
            return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the class which you are going to use the new `Add` method, first add the using statement:

```
using MyExtensions;
```

Then use it like a normal method:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("One", 1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to integrate your code into my code. Against the backdrop of my existing classes `DRT_Tvw_Abstract` and `DRT_Tvw_TableList_Unfiltered`, where does you code go so that I can access my `Metrics` fields? (see updates to my code in the question).

Comment: Edited the answer to show you hot to use extension method.

Comment: In my case, the `string text` argument needs to be a class of mine derived from a `TreeNode`. When I modify  `public static TreeNode Add(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, string text, int tag)` to `public static TreeNode Add(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, MyTreeNodeClass myTreeNodeClass, int tag)` the call `treeView1.Nodes.Add(myTreeNodeClass, 1);` won't compile: `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'myTreeNodeClass' of 'TreeNodeCollectionExtensions.Add(TreeNodeCollection, TreeNode)'`. I'm reading the `Extension Methods` link to figure it out

Comment: Starting to wonder about `Extensions`. From [Extension Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods): `In general, we recommend that you implement extension methods sparingly and only when you have to. Whenever possible, client code that must extend an existing type should do so by creating a new type derived from the existing type. When using an extension method to extend a type whose source code you cannot change, you run the risk that a change in the implementation of the type will cause your extension method to break`

Comment: About the compiler error, it seems it's ambiguous between your method and an existing method of the `TreeNodeCollection`, you can solve it by using named parameters, or using a different method name.

Comment: About extension methods. What I can say is: It will be one of the best things that you can learn as a C# developer. Apart from extension methods, keep the first bullet point in mind, `TreeNodeCollection` doesn't have a public constructor, so you cannot drive from it. Anyway, you are the one which should choose the solution.

Comment: I guess that's the point: I recognize that the `TreeNodeCollection` ctor is sealed, but that's irrelevant because I'm not trying to derive a class from it. What I'm trying to do is override `Nodes.Add(X)` where `Nodes` is a property of `TreeView` and `X` is a class of mine derived from the `TreeNode` class.  I'm trying to figure out how to override the `Add` method which is a virtual method. I should be able to override it

Comment: It's relevant, in fact the main important point in the answer. `Nodes` is property of `TreeView`. `Nodes` is of type `TreeNodeCollection`. `Add` is the method of `TreeNodeCollection`. You can not override `Add` without deriving from `TreeNodeCollection`. Read the first bullet point carefully.

Comment: ok, abandoned the `Add` method override approach and went back to an extension. Tried using a different method name, same error CS7036. I give up :-(

Comment: Without seeing your code we cannot help. If you need to share the code, do it in a new question, just refer to this question. Make sure you include [MCVE].

Comment: Please see [Why can't the compiler figure out what the 2nd formal parameter is for my TreeNodeCollection extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117529/why-cant-the-compiler-figure-out-what-the-2nd-formal-parameter-is-for-my-treeno)

Comment: I read the new question. You are using the extension method wrong. I believe here I've provided a completely clear example. Follow the example here.

Comment: Sorry - yes - agreed

Comment: For other readers: Short version is: you can't override the TreeNodeCollection Add method. Reza's answer to [Why can't the compiler figure out what the 2nd formal parameter is for my TreeNodeCollection extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117529/why-cant-the-compiler-figure-out-what-the-2nd-formal-parameter-is-for-my-treeno) shows how to use an extension method so you can get your hooks into the TreeNodeCollection Nodes.Add method