# What is the correct way to call an extension method (TreeNodeCollection Add method)?

Tags: c#, winforms, extension-methods, treenodecollection

The pertinent parts of my code are below. In the `MyTreeView` class (last block of code below), the line of code `TncExtensions.TncNodeAdd(this, myTreeViewNode);` generates the error `CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'myTreeViewNode' of 'TncExtensions.TncNodeAdd(TreeNodeCollection, MyTreeView_Abstract, MyTreeViewNode_Abstract)'`

Why can't the compiler figure out what the 2nd formal parameter is for my TreeNodeCollection extension method?

```cs
public static class TncExtensions
{
    public static int TncNodeAdd(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, MyTreeView_Abstract myTreeView, MyTreeViewNode_Abstract myTreeViewNode)
    {
        return myTreeView.Nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode);
    }
}

public abstract class MyTreeViewNode_Abstract : TreeNode
{
    public MyTreeViewNode_Abstract(string text) : base(text)
    {
    }
}

public class MyTreeViewNode : MyTreeViewNode_Abstract
{
    public MyTreeViewNode(string text) : base(text)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class MyTreeView_Abstract : TreeView
{
}

public class MyTreeView : MyTreeView_Abstract
{
    public void CreateTree()
    {
        MyTreeViewNode myTreeViewNode = new MyTreeViewNode("node text");
        TncExtensions.TncNodeAdd(this, myTreeViewNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared an extension method, but you used it like a normal static method. If you call it like a normal static method, **all** arguments need to be provided (in your case 3, not just 2). That said, it kinda looks wrong trying to call an extension method like a normal static method. Perhaps look into a tutorial about extension methods to clarify how they are usually used/called.

Comment: You are using the extension method wrong.

Comment: Also, what precisely is the purpose of the `nodes` argument in your extension method? Your extension method is not using `nodes`, so what is the point of it having it there?

Comment: @HansPassant:   I have to disagree. Originally, I was using the base `TreeNodeCollection Add` method to add a custom `TreeView` node to a custom `TreeView`. In my custom `TreeView`, I have custom properties that track the state of my custom `TreeView`. Without getting hooks into the `Add` method, I had to update the custom properties using inline code immediately after **each** call to the base `Add` method . By using an `Add` extension method and a custom property that ties the custom node to the custom `TreeView`, I can update the custom `TreeView` properties in one central location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the extension method which you created is not of much use but if you are curious to know what the problem is, you are using the extension method wrong. You are accessing it like a static method, in this style you need to pass 3 arguments based on the signature of the method:

```
TncExtensions.TncNodeAdd(Nodes, this, myTreeViewNode);
```

Or use it like an extension method:

```
this.Nodes.TncNodeAdd(this, myTreeViewNode);
```

I suggest you change the extension method to:

```
public static int TncNodeAdd(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, MyTreeViewNode_Abstract myTreeViewNode)
{
    return nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode);
}
```

To learn more, take a look at [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance on how to use the extension method correctly. I wasn't getting it (obviously). The extension method doesn't look like much because I provided only the minimal code required to ask my question. Now that you've taught me how to call the extension method correctly, I can achieve the goal stated in the  [original override question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089409/how-do-i-override-treenodecollection-addtreenode): `increment/decrement custom integer properties that are part of my MyTreeView class at the same time I Add a MyTreeViewNode to my MyTreeView`.

Comment: p.s.: After I modified my calling code to be IAW with your answer, I was able to rename the extension method to simply  `Add`

Comment: Yes, you can, there is no naming conflict.

Comment: One more update (your answer is still the accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

Reza'a answer is still the answer, but to make my treenode `Add` extension method useful, I had to modify my calls to it. I forgot that as part of adding a treenode, you need to specify what node collection you want to append the new node to.

Note: See code in original question for the basic classes involved

**Modified Add extension method as suggested by Reza**

```
namespace TreeNodeCollectionExtensions
{
    public static class TncExtensions
    {
        public static int Add(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, DRT.DRT_TvwNode_Abstract myTreeViewNode)
        {
            int newNodeIndex = nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode);

            //Do stuff to custom properties that are members of DRT_TvwNode_Abstract and classes derived from DRT_TvwNode_Abstract

            return newNodeIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

**Use it like this**

```
using TreeNodeCollectionExtensions;

public class MyTreeView : MyTreeView_Abstract
{
    public MyTreeView() : base()
    {
    }

    public void CreateTree()
    {
        MyTreeViewNode myTreeViewNode;

        //Add node to root of TreeView 
        //Using named parameter to force the compiler to
        //use the Add extension method and not the base Add method
        myTreeViewNode = new MyTreeViewNode("root node text");
        Nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode: myTreeViewNode);

        //Add node one level below root node of TreeView
        //Using named parameter to force the compiler to
        //use the Add extension method and not the base Add method
        myTreeViewNode = new MyTreeViewNode("level 1 node text");
        int newLevel1NodeIndex = Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode: myTreeViewNode);

        //Add node one level below level 1 node just created 
        //Using named parameter to force the compiler to
        //use the Add extension method and not the base Add method
        myTreeViewNode = new MyTreeViewNode("level 2 node text");
        int newLevel2NodeIndex = Nodes[0].Nodes[newLevel1NodeIndex].Nodes.Add(myTreeViewNode: myTreeViewNode);

        //etc., etc.

    }
}
```

Comment: `this TreeNodeCollection nodes` this is the node collection which you are going to add to it. What's the point of having the second parameter? When you call `treeView1.Nodes.Add()` why do you want to have another node collection as parameter? You have the nodes collection in the first parameter of extension method.

Comment: I'm not sure you have got the usage of extension methods correctly. An extension method is going to add a new method to an instance of object, and always, you define that instance as first parameter of the method. But when calling the extension method, you don't need to pass the object to the method. For example. Let's say you create a `Reverse` extension method for string: `public static string Reverse (this string input)`, then as the usage, it's enough to call it like this: `someString.Reverse()` without passing the instance. In fact `someString` will be passed as `input` to the method.

Comment: You're right - I'm um... struggling to understand this stuff. I started as a developer in the 80's (procedural programming). Started learning OOD//OOP and C# recently. It has been/is a challenge. I fixed my update. I think I have it now